# Is is possible to convert this recursive function to tail-recursive using continuation passing style?

Tags: recursion, f#, monads, tail-recursion

I have recently written an ETL, which works just fine.
I would like to remind myself how to use free monads, so would like to convert my ETL as such.
Note: my intention here is not to write a better ETL, but to re-familiarize myself with free monads. In re-learing how free monads work, I got side tracked with the topic of this question.

So I asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411886/does-using-a-free-monad-in-f-imply-a-higher-startup-time-and-limited-instructio) some months ago. Someone commented that my recursive function could be made tail-recursive using continuation passing style. I can't figure out how to do it.

Some sample code:

```
type In1 = int
type In2 = int
type Out1 = int
type Out2 = int

type FaceInstruction<'a> =
| Member1 of (In1 * (Out1 -> 'a))
| Member2 of (In2 * (Out2 -> 'a))

let private mapI f = function
    | Member1 (x, next) -> Member1 (x, next >> f)
    | Member2 (x, next) -> Member2 (x, next >> f)

type FaceProgram<'a> =
| Free of FaceInstruction<FaceProgram<'a>>
| Pure of 'a

let rec bind f = function
| Free x -> x |> mapI (bind f) |> Free
| Pure x -> f x
```

The function I am trying to make tail recusrive is `bind`

My attempts look something like

```
let rec bind2 (f: 'a -> FaceProgram<'b>) k  z : FaceProgram<'b> = 
    match z with
    |Pure x -> x |> f |> k
    |Free x -> bind2 ???
```

I am starting to think that, in fact, it is not possible to make this tail recursive. The type `FaceInstruction<'a>` already includes a continuation, and the function `mapI` modifies that continuation, so now trying to add another continuation `k` is one of two more continuations than I can handle right now!

Comment: As AMieres points out, `bind` is actually a binary function, so when you call `bind f` it's only partially applied in this context. No recursion happens. In the `Free` case, we simply compose `next >> (bind f)` which produces a _new_ function, but does not _evaluate_ our function. In the `Pure` case, we perform the evaluation of the composed function sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality `bind` is not actually a recursive function in the sense that in the stack there is never going to be more than one call to `bind` at any given time.

The reason is because neither `bind` nor `mapI` call `bind`. Notice how they both exit immediately without going deeper into the stack. `bind` calls `mapI` but `mapI` does not call any function at all (apart from `Member1` or `Member2` which are constructor functions). What they do is compose a new Free monad instance using `bind` and `next`. `bind` has to be declared as `rec` because it needs a self-reference to pass itself as a parameter to `mapI`.

It is the interpreter that needs to be implemented as tail recursive, which should not be too difficult.